# How to install an old version of TestFlight on an iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I would like to test an IOS application on an iPhone 6, but for that, I need to install TestFlight.  However, the latest version of TestFlight is only compatible with IOS13. Which is not supported on iPhone 6.

So the question is: How can I run an old version of TestFlight on the iPhone 6? or what are the workarounds.

Comment: by the way, before there is update from Apple, i have installed testflight on my iphone 5s and it is workable. So technically the old version works but we need to get it somewhere

Answer (score -2):

If someone has the old TestFlight Appstore build you can install it via XCode.